# Wordpress media library is not showing imgs while adding img in new post or form

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress, when I open the media library, it shows all the images in the media library. But whenever I try to add new pictures in any post/page/form and proceed to insert media from the library, it does not show any image and continuously reading gallery.

[image]

Comment: That is sad. Can you be more specific and provide more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probably is that your theme or one of your plugin is causing this issue. I recommend you to do this task for debugging the issue:

- First off all make sure to have WP_DEBUG turn on in your wp-config.php file: [Debugging in WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). If you see any error, fix it. If no error, continue to the next task.
- Activate the default WordPress theme Twenty Fifteen and try to add and image to a post again, if it doesn't work, it means that your theme is not the problem. Continue to the next task.
- Deactivate all your plugin, one by one, and try to add an image to a post after each plugin deactivation. If after deactivating all the plugins the error continues... the next task.
- If nothing works, I will re-install WordPress. You can keep your themes, plugins and media by keeping the wp-content folder. Just delete wp-admin, wp-include and all the files, download a new version of WordPress and upload again this files.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the problem was with a multi language issue (plugin Polylang).
The pictures were associated with a specific language, somehow.
To fix : go to "Languages", then "Settings", then desactivate for Media :

"Activate languages and translations for media"